# Publish messages to Kafka cluster from remote machine

Tags: apache-kafka, remote-server, kafka-producer-api

I am new with Kafka and I have a Kafka Cluster setup on my local machine. How can I publish messages to it from a remote server which is not on my network?

Answer (score 0):

If you local machine IP is not public then you can not access it from a machine on another network. You will need a static IP as it is accessible from outside.